# Kibana start dev environment

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to embed one my specific chart in dahsboard of kibana. For that I need inject my JS into Kibana source. I have followed by instructions https://github.com/elastic/kibana/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md to provide test environment, but I have obtained an error after "./kibana --dev"

```
let _ = require('lodash');
^^^

node.js:201
         throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
          ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected strict mode reserved word
     at Module._compile (module.js:429:25)
    at Object..js (module.js:459:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:348:32)
    at Function._load (module.js:308:12)
    at Array.0 (module.js:479:10)
    at EventEmitter._tickCallback (node.js:192:41)
```

Can anybody help me with start environment, or advice. Probably, I am moving by wrong way...my general goal (inject my JS code into Kibana) can be reached by another approach.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

## LINUX.

源自CONTRIBUTING.md

#### Development Environment Setup

- Install node.js (we recommend using [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm))

  follow directions at github.com/creationix/nvm, then

  ```sh

  nvm install v0.10.35

  ```
- Install grunt and bower globally (as root if not using nvm)

  ```sh

  npm install -g grunt-cli bower

  ```
- Clone the kibana repo and move into it

  ```sh

  git clone https://github.com/elastic/kibana.git kibana

  cd kibana

  git tag && git checkout v4.1.1

  ```
- Install node and bower dependencies

  ```sh

  npm install && bower install --allow-root

  ```
- Start the development server.

  If do not install elasticksearch in you ENV, please use the "--with-es" flag to install & start elasticsearch too
  ```sh

  grunt dev

  ```

  基于源代码，修改后，执行
  grunt build --force   #跳过README warning部分